# Looking for a bill scanning OCR tool that I can build into a React Native App for an academic project. Any suggestions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ocr, scanning

Hey I'm looking for a good ocr api/tool that I could build into my react-native app.
The tool should be able to scan bills and I want to retrieve the name of the place and the total price from the bill.Please help me out in finding a suitable tool or api.
I'm a college student so I'm not able to get my hands onto those commercials tools available online.

Thanks

Comment: Well without knowing any of your tech requirements outside of react-native, probably the best place to start is the `react-native-tesseract-ocr` module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tesseract-ocr. Tesseract is a free, fairly well known, open source technology for OCR.

Comment: tesseract is gold. nice that they have a js module

Comment: I primarily need it for scanning bills which tend to be of different sizes and formats so is there any other better tool out there because I've read that tesseract isn't that accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in [this blog](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/comparing-on-device-text-recognition-ocr-sdks-24f8a0423461) using [React Native Text Detector](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector) hope this can help you. It reads the business card and returns all the text on it.
What you can do is to add Regular Expressions for detecting different attributes. Let's say billing amount will have currency logo before or after the text or for more accuracy add expected region where the billing amount should be. RNTextDetector also returns the bounding of the text on the image. There is also a mapping function that translates boundings on an image to boundings on screen for better user experience. This tutorial can be a good point to start from and then keep on adding things on top of it.